# Best way to reorganize arrays index by Dojo/jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I made a list of components that user can add/remove rows of input fields at liberty, so user can freely remove/add a row of data dynamically:

----|**_**||____| -remove button-

----|**_**||____| -remove button-

----|**_**||____| -remove button-

----|**_**||____| -remove button-

----Add button-       ---- Save button ----

However, here comes a problem: the data is arranged in html arrays in order to get back to JSP/sevlet model, like thie

```
  <input id="row[0]" .../>
  <input id="row[1]" .../>
  <input id="row[2]" .../>
                ......
  <input id="row[n]" .../>
```

So when user remove a row, especially in the middle of the section, then the array sequence is definitely messed up because I just use basic jquery command to do the job:

```
        if (confirm(message_confirm_delete)) {
            j(this).parent().remove();
        }
```

so the question is: what is the best way to re-arrange all of the input fields array, when  user remove one of the array elements between?

Comment: Can you just use http://api.jquery.com/index/ for the row's id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're saying the ids on the input fields are inaccurate after removing one from the middle, correct?  If that is the case, something like this will update the id attribute after an element is removed.

```
<div>
    <input id="row[0]" type="text" class="removableInput"/><button class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="row[1]" type="text" class="removableInput"/><button class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="row[2]" type="text" class="removableInput"/><button class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="row[3]" type="text" class="removableInput"/><button class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="row[4]" type="text" class="removableInput"/><button class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="row[5]" type="text" class="removableInput"/><button class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>      

<script>
    $('button.remove').click(function() {
        $(this).parent('div').remove();

        $('input.removableInput').each(function(index) {
            $(this).attr('id', 'row[' + index + ']');
        });                                 
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Could you suggest any advice on re-assign id for Dom by Dojo? Appreciate.

Comment: I'm not much of a dojo person but it looks like you can use the attr function: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/attr.html#dojo-attr.